# Why "New Fault message" is missing when editing Port Operation in Biztalk orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I want to handle fault from WCF webservice (simple service created with default settings).

But for some reason when I added port to Orchestration (Created via "Add Generated Item") and do right click on port operation there is no "New Fault Message"

What could be reason that "New Fault Message" is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Do  you have a fault message(schema) on the message type, if you dont have the Fault message type on the generated items, you wont have it defining the port, if you are trying with a Dynamics AX, you just need to enable the port, in short you should have it on your WSDL definition to be able to add it.

Comment: I have default VS 2013 4.5 WCF project not Dynamics AX. Is there way to check if Fault is in WSDL  ? Is there way to add default Fault into webservice ? All examples I googled have Custom Fault class.I  don't need custom, just default Fault class.

Comment: You need to configure the port in order to have the fault message available on you WSDL.

Configure error messaging
You can configure the integration port to provide information about errors by using the following check boxes:
**Include exceptions in fault**

 Select this check box to specify that X++ and .NET Framework error messages from the service are included in fault messages. When you select this check box, the fault message includes detailed Infolog messages.

PD: you need to disable and enable the port in order to do this.... so be carefull if you are in PROD